# CountDownUp in c program

Tags: c, countdown

I want to create a CountDownUP program but the code is not working, I want it to output `5 4 3 2 1 0 1 2 3 4 5` but it only outputs `5 4 3 2 1 0 1`

```
void countDownUp (unsigned int k){
    printf("\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < k; i=1){
        k = k - i;
        printf("%d ", k);
    }

    for (int n = 0; n <= k; n++){
        printf("%d ",n);
    }
}

int main(){
    int num;
    fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%d", &num);

    countDownUp (num);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why `i=1` in the first `for` loop?

Comment: There's no need for `fflush(stdout)` before printing anything.

Comment: Your number is larger than the maximum int possible value, you should consider using long or any larger data type or limiting the input.

Comment: if i don't put (i = 1) the countdown doesn't work

Comment: Normally the third part of a `for` loop header is the increment or decrement of the iteration variable. It's not clear why you even need `i`. `for (; k > 1; k--)` would do the same thing.

Comment: @yxor The output isn't a single number, it's just the result of counting down and up. There's actually a space between each number.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first `for` loop decrements `k` each time through the loop, and stops when `k == 1`. So the second loop just iterates from `0` to `1`.

You shouldn't modify `k` in the first loop, you should decrement `i`.

```
for (int i = k; i > 1; i--) {
    printf("%d ", i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, you can do it using one `for` with:

```
for(int i = k; i >= -k; i--)
        if(i <= -1)
            printf("%d ", -i);
        else
            printf("%d ", i);
```